# How to retrieve an order from the database? Magento version 2.1.0

Tags: magento-2.1, database, orders

```
Magento 2.1.0
Porto theme
```

I have a problem with Magento 2.1.0 - it gives the

```
"Attention

Something went wrong." Error message."
```

I have not been able to fix that.

Now someone placed an order and I am not able to see it (because of the Error).

**How to retrieve order info from the database?**

*PS: I just found out that a different (not Admin) user account is showing SALES - ORDERS while my Admin account gives the Error. What could be the reason for that?*

Comment: open your browser console and check what is the error and update your question with error details.

Comment: @Sohel Rana This Error comes up in Admin under SALES - ORDERS...would that still show a more specific Error in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Attention error, many times coming due not loading js properly.

But you can get order by using sales order model in following way:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

$orderInfo = (array)$orderData->getData();

print_r($orderInfo);
```

If you want to see order info in db, then see this 'sales_order' table into database.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Where can I put the code you included so that I can retrieve the order info? Thanks again. Also - how would I check/correct the js loading thing?

Comment: I am in the database and I found the "mydatabasename_sales_order" table. When I click it - it shows the list of orders (there are 5) - how would I actually display the contents of the individual orders? Is there some kind of a SQL query for that?

Comment: Hi Allysin,
Please get the code for getting order info by going into given below link
http://brijeshtech.in/magento2-get-order-info-by-order-id/

Please put the code into the root location of magento.

You can see the js error into browser error console.

Comment: I created a file called orders.php and placed the code in it. When I access www.mysite.com/orders.php - it gives the following Error: Notice: Use of undefined constant ORDER_ENTITY_ID - assumed 'ORDER_ENTITY_ID' in /home/mySITE/public_html/orders.php on line 10     If I try to enter the order number instead of ORDER_ENTITY_ID or $orderId = it does not load. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: ORDER_ENTITY_ID means the entity id of order.

Comment: ORDER_ENTITY_ID means the entity id of order.
value of entity_id column in sales_order table. you can see this id value into sales_order table or into the sales order section admin.

Comment: I am really really sorry - I am not so good with these things - I can do HTML, upload, download and modify files via FTP, I can find my way into the phpMyAdmin, WHM, cPanel but I really don't know what you want me to do with this ORDER_ENTITY_ID?

Comment: http://brijeshtech.in/magento2-get-order-info-by-order-id/

see this code again and pass that order id which order's info you want to get
instead of 3

Comment: I did and I get a blank screen. I tried both the order ID and the Entity ID which I found in the mysite_sales_order table. The Entity ID's for my 5 orders appear to be 1,2, 3, 4 and 5. The order ID should be: 000000021

Comment: Then, need to be look orders.. why it's not coming may be there are some serious issue.